# how can i make a textfield that only accepts letters backspace and spacebar only

Tags: java

i need to have a textfield that does not show anything if the user typed special characters or numbers. i have this Name textfield and i need to narrow it to letters input only. the user can also backspace and shift (by using keypress or keytyped or keyrelease whichever be better)

EDITED.

Comment: I'd use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), there are some really excellent examples [here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Comment: @MadProgrammer since that's the canonical answer, I'd suggest you make it one (with just a little more meat... I'll upvote :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison It's really hard to fill out "I've answered this question a million times" in an answer :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I understand, having been there myself.  You could vote to close as a duplicate :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison It's more similar then a duplicate, but the basic answer is the same, you want to filter the input of a field, use the `DocumentFilter` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DocumentFilter` is your friend in this situation.

> DocumentFilter, as the name implies, is a filter for the Document
>   mutation methods

I would also [MDP's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for some excellent examples.